# Getting text in scrollview to start at the top, not the bottom (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

In my view, I load some text content in from a database within the `viewDidLoad` section of code.

This works fine and looks fine, but the scrollview sits at the very bottom of the text when the app is run.

I added this code below:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear: animated];
[self.descriptionTextV setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
}
```

And this now moves the scroll view to the top of the text, which is what I want, but it takes a couple of seconds to do this, and it is distracting.

I have tried

```
[self.descriptionTextV setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

Which moves the text with an animated scroll over a few seconds.

```
[self.descriptionTextV setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
```

Which 'jumps' the text from the bottom to the top.

And I have tried moving the `setContentOffset` command to the `viewDidLoad` and to a `viewWillAppear` section, but then it doesn't work at all.

Is there any way to get my text to start at the TOP of the text, not the bottom, without it animating, scrolling or jumping?

I just want the text to start at the top, and for there to be no visual jump that the user can see in the final app.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but how about `...animated:NO` called from `viewWillAppear` (not viewDidAppear)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now managed to get this working by moving my code to the following method:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.descriptionTextV setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
```

And this works great!

Answer (score 0):

If I had the correct understanding out of your problem, you're using a `UITextView` to load your text into, what makes this problem really odd, since the default behavior of `UITextView` is to start from top. If this is the case, make sure that no other actions is being performed on the text view. Also, you might want take a look on how long you're taking to load your data.